# Getting Source object from footnote (word vba)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I create footnotes which contains Source objects (a Source object is a single object from Sources list, from which I create Bibliography)
All I want to do is to loop through all footnotes and get XML file from each Source object to retrieve information about Author and so on.
I have problem with getting Source object from footnotes. I tried to select footnote and retrieve this object from selection but nothing works. Maybe You guys have a proper way to retrieve "parent object" from another object in vba?

```
Sub convertAllFootnotes()
 Dim ftn As Footnote
 Dim oRng As Range
  For Each ftn In ActiveDocument.Footnotes
    Set oRng = Selection.Range
    oRng.Start = oRng.Start - 1
    oRng.End = oRng.End + 1
    oRng.Select
    oRng.Text = stringFromSource(ftn) 'i don't know how to get source object 
                                  'from footnote
  Next ftn
End Sub
```

string from source function (which works properly, i must pass to it Surce object)

```
Function stringFromSource(curField As Source) As String
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.LoadXML curField.XML
authors = "":  title = "": publish = "": city = "": year = "": periodic = 
""
'authors
Set surname = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("b:Last")
Set name = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("b:First")
Dim l As Integer
l = 0
For Each el In surname
    If el.Text = "" Then Exit For
    authors = authors + (el.Text & " " & name(l).Text & "  ")
    l = l + 1
Next el
'title
Set titlex = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("b:Title")
For Each el In titlex
    If el.Text = "" Then Exit For
    title = title + (el.Text & " ")
Next el
'publisher
Set pubx = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("b:Publisher")
For Each el In pubx
    publish = publish + (el.Text & " ")
Next el
'city
Set cityx = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("b:City")
If cityx.Length = 0 Then city = city + ("(brak miasta)" & " ")
For Each el In cityx
    city = city + (el.Text & " ")
Next el
'year
Set yearx = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("b:Year")
If yearx.Length = 0 Then year = year + ("(brak roku wydania)" & " ")
For Each el In yearx
    year = year + (el.Text & " ")
Next el
'periodical title
Set periodx = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("b:PeriodicalTitle")
For Each el In period
    periodic = periodic + (el.Text & " ")
Next el

Dim outputString As String
outputString = author & "- " & title & ", " & publish & periodic & ", " & 
year
stringFromSource = outputString
End Function
```

Comment: publish code, please

Comment: up.............

Comment: What is  Selection.Range? What  is  curField.XML?